# how to automatically delete a record from the database in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

i have a rails table setup called products and its all working well, lets assume i want to auto delete a record 3 weeks after creation how do go about the code

my product db is as follows

```
class Products < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.text :description
      t.string :price
      t.string :name
      t.string :contact
      t.attachment :photo
      t.string :slug
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :products, :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: See my answer, I too faced the same situation. And I did what i have explained in my answer. It may help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways on how to handle this task. Check 2 options below.

**Option 1 - [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem**

You would setup a task using whenever which runs for example every 30 days.

1- Generate task as following:

`rails g task posts delete_30_days_old`

2- Create a ruby file in your application

```
# lib/tasks/delete_old_records.rb
namespace :posts do
  desc "Delete records older than 30 days"
  task delete_30_days_old: :environment do
    Post.where(['created_at < ?', 30.days.ago]).destroy_all
  end
end
```

**Option 2 - [sidekick](http://sidekiq.org/) and [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) gems**

```
# in app/workers/clean_posts.rb
class CleanPosts
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { monthly }

  def perform
    Post.recent.destroy_all
  end
end
```

and

```
# /models/post.rb
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :recent, -> { where('created_at >= :thirty_days_ago', thiryty_days_ago: Time.now - 30.days) }
end
```

Since Ruby is about beauty, move the where clause to your model, where can reuse it.

These options will remove old posts from your DB and they will no longer be accessible by your application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a cron Job, Which has to run each day at a particular time. To set up a Cron job you can use the Gem [WHENEVER](https://github.com/javan/whenever)

And the Query should be like

```
Product.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 3.weeks).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want automatically an action, you should use cron job in your app. I have an app using [clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) gem for schedule some process on background.

### Step by step :

Put this on your Gemfile

```
gem 'clockwork'
gem 'foreman'
```

Create file `clock.rb` on folder `app`

```
require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
 every(1.day, 'delete.product', :at => '00:00') {
   Product.where("created_at >= ?", 3.week.ago.utc).destroy_all
 }
end
```

Running test clockwork

```
clockwork app/clock.rb
```

Example, this is my app using clockwork with delete automatically user every 30.seconds  :

```
C:\Sites\multiple>clockwork app/clock.rb
I, [2013-06-12T13:36:14.380239 #2356]  INFO -- : Starting clock for 1 events: [
delete.user ]
I, [2013-06-12T13:36:14.380239 #2356]  INFO -- : Triggering 'delete.user'
I, [2013-06-12T13:36:44.784978 #2356]  INFO -- : Triggering 'delete.user'
```

Or If you want running clockwork with the app, you cold using foreman looks like :

```
foreman start
```

**Note** : running foreman you should install foreman on your machine

Comment: I think `product.each do` should be `@products.each do` no?

Answer (score 0):

Create a rake task and run that rake task periodically. Something like:

delete_old_products.rake:

```
task delete_old_products: :environment do
  Product.where("created_at <= ?", Time.now - 3.weeks).each do |product|
    product.destroy
  end
end
```

You can run that from the command line with `rake delete_old_products`