# Is there a way destroy an object based on a date attribute as opposed to created_at in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am aware that there is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17058344/how-to-automatically-delete-a-record-from-the-database-in-rails) similar to what I am asking but this question is in regards to deletion a certain time after object creation (created_at) but I have many event objects with a specific date when they take place. I want to destroy that event object after that date, which will then trigger an email either thanking attendees or apologizing for missing them if they did not attend. Is there a way to accomplish destroying the object based on one of it's attributes? Or can this only be accomplished using the created_at attribute?

The dates are currently a string but eventually I will have them become a datetime attribute if that makes a difference.

In my events.rake file:

```
namespace :events do
  desc "Delete event after 12 hours from date"
  task delete_12_hours_old: :environment do
    Event.where(['date < ?', 12.hours.ago]).destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: If you can delete them based on `created_at` you certainly should be able to find and delete based on `date` instead, it is just a different field in the same table, can you share the code you have so far?  In reference to the question you shared, you would replace the `created_at` in red with `date` or whatever the column is called.

Comment: Yeah here is what I have in my events.rake file: `namespace :events do desc "Delete event after 12 hours from date" task delete_12_hours_old::environment do .where(['date < ?', 12.hours.ago]).destroy_all endend`

Comment: post code in the question by editing it please, just add it into the question and format it

Comment: @RockwellRice sorry will do!

Comment: What exactly is not working with your solution? To me it looks correct, although you might shorten it to `Event.destroy_all('date < ?', 12.hours.ago)`. If you want to trigger actions in reaction to this, you can use the 'before_destroy' callback.

Comment: @morgler I created an event with an end_date of 1AM, hoping it would be destroyed at 1PM (a few minutes ago) but I didn't notice any deletions. I have my server running but I am using localhost:3000 so I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: This might not be the cause, but I know `12.hours.ago` to cause timezone issues. It calculates a different time than say `Time.zone.now - 12.hours`. You might want to check that time calculation separately from the deletion problem. If that wasn't the cause, you might want to check the collection your query delivers (`Event.where(…)`). If that is correct, you might want to check the destroy lifecycle callbacks (`before_destroy` and so on).

Comment: @morgler that's actually what I ended up doing! I also utilized the whenever gem and made a rake task that checks the database every two minutes to check for events who's `end_time`'s are less than `Time.now = 12.hours`! I will post an answer shortly but there is a lot of great documentation for whenever! Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and was able to make a rake task that runs every 2 minutes checking the database for events who's `end_date` is less than `Time.now - 12.hours`. Any that meet this criteria are removed from the database. I ran into some issues but [this thread](https://github.com/javan/whenever/issues/665) was extremely helpful.

Following the steps I ended up writing a schedule.rb in my config directory which housed the rake task. In my schedule.rb file:

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, {:error => "log/cron_error_log.log", :standard => "log/cron_log.log"}
every 2.minutes do
  rake "events:delete_12_hours_old"
end
```

In lib/tasks/events.rake file:

```
namespace :events do

  desc "Delete event after 12 hours from date"
  task delete_12_hours_old: :environment do
    Event.where('end_date <= ?', Time.now-12.hours).destroy_all
  end

end
```

Thank you guys for all of the help and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an attribute of `delete_after` and set a date on it. Then you'd probably want to create a rake task that will select all events in the db where `current_data > delete_at`. Then you'd want a cron or scheduler to handle automatically running this rake task for you on some sort of maintenance interval (refer to the original link you posted for delayed jobs or scheduled tasks that happen in the future).

Setting this attribute will also allow the user to update the event if they ever need to reschedule.